# Deriving key with OpenSCv14.0

Tags: openssl

I am trying to derive a secret key with OpenSC tool. I generated EC key with help of openssl through following command:

```
openssl ecparam -in secp384r1param.pem -genkey -noout -out secp384r1key.pem
```

& tried to pass this key to opensc derive command:

```
pkcs11-tool.exe --module opensc-pkcs11.dll --derive -l -pin #### -id 03 -i secp384r1key.pem
```

But this gave me output:

> Cannot read EC key from secp384r1key.pem

A small debugging showed me that openssl function `d2i_EC_PUBKEY_bio` is throwing this error. I tried to find any help on input file format for this but no avail.
Can you guys help me out? Where I am being wrong in the process? I have just started working with smart cards & readers.

Comment: note that many smart cards only support up to 320-bit ECC meaning P-384 would be too large. And also note that most smartcards won't accept externally generated private keys for local storage.

Comment: @SEJPM it appears to me (but I don't know for certain) `--derive` does ECDH derivation of a local (oncard) privatekey against a (nominally) remote publickey, which conforms to the security model. The curve size may indeed be an issue, but only after getting the parameters so the program can make the card request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenSSL `{d2i,i2d}_$type[_$io]` routines read and write DER (d2i means DER-to-internal, i2d means internal-to-DER); `PEM_{read,write}[_$io]_$type` read and write PEM. Routines where type is `[$alg_]PUBKEY` read and write public keys in generic X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo form, which is usually preferred (although there are alternatives). You have a private key in PEM format (nongeneric, but that doesn't matter) and the program wants a public key in generic DER format. Do

```
openssl ec -in blahkeyfile.pem -out blahpubfile.der -pubout -outform der
```

(or suitable name of your choice) and try using that instead.